# Select from two tables and insert into one if it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
Members
 - Person_id
Sites
 - Site_id
Member_multi_site
 - Person_id
 - Site_id
```

What I am trying to do is insert the `Person_id` and `Site_id` into the `Member_multi_site` table when the same row does not exist in the `Member_multi_site` table.

So if in the `Sites` table there are 3 rows `1` `2` `3` And in the `Members` table there is 1 row `1` it should add them like so into the `Member_multi_site` table:

```
-----------------------
| Person_id | Site_id |
-----------------------
|     1     |    1    |
|     1     |    2    |
|     1     |    3    |
```

I managed to get it working by manually inserting the `Site_id` like so:

```
SET @id = 0;

INSERT INTO
 Member_multi_site (
  Person_id,
  Site_id,
 )
SELECT
 Person_id,
 @id,
FROM
 Members
WHERE
 Person_id
 NOT IN (
  SELECT
   Person_id
  FROM
   Member_multi_site
  WHERE
   Site_id = @id
 )
```

I can't figure out how to alter this query so I dont have to manually put in the `Site_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cross join` the tables and insert the rows if they don't already exist.

```
INSERT INTO
 Member_multi_site (
  Person_id,
  Site_id
 )
SELECT
 Person_id,
 Site_id
FROM
 Members
 CROSS JOIN Sites 
WHERE Person_id NOT IN (SELECT Person_id FROM Member_multi_site)
AND Site_id NOT IN (SELECT Site_id FROM Member_multi_site)
```

Or you can use `not exists`

```
INSERT INTO
 Member_multi_site (
  Person_id,
  Site_id
 )
SELECT
 Person_id,
 Site_id
FROM
 Members m
 CROSS JOIN Sites s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Member_multi_site
                  where person_id = m.person_id and site_id = s.site_id)
```

Comment: what is the error you get? there is a comma after the last column in the insert?

Comment: Yeah that fixed it

Comment: Performance wise both of your queries seem a little slower and uses more actions on the server than Eralper's answer, however readability is a lot better on your queries.

Comment: Another note. Your first query after the first time it has been run, if you try deleting a few rows from the `Member_multi_site` table and execute it once more it doesn't fill the ones you have deleted. Your second query does that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Please check following SQL Script on a test environment
I hope it helps

```
insert into Member_multi_site (
    Person_id, Site_id
)
select
    t.Person_id, t.Site_id
from (
    select Person_id, Site_id from Members, Sites
) t
left join Member_multi_site m 
    on m.Person_id = t.Person_id and 
       m.Site_id = t.Site_id
where m.Site_id is null
```

Comment: Thanks for the query however it doesn't check if the row already exists in the table `Member_multi_site`

Comment: Hello, the LEFT JOIN to member_multi_site and WHERE clause with IS NULL check on member_multi_site row checks and eliminates existing rows to be inserted again. Please test again. I tried with different cases and get the desired result each time.

Comment: If I run your query twice it will insert the data twice. Tested this out.

Comment: Please check the WHERE clause "where m.Site_id is null" is the alias or column name false? You can play around with these maybe.